# How to autocomplete hyphenated directory name in OSX terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, autocomplete

I have this set of folders on 2 macbooks both running the latest version of El Capitan.

- `foo-bar`
- `foo-bar2`

On one system, hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> after `cd f` gives me `cd foo-`.

On the other system, I get `cd foo`.

I would like to other system to also include the `-` into the autocomplete result, but I'm not sure how. I can't find any particular setting within terminal or iterm2 to configure. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have yet another directory on the second system? With a name starting with foo, for example `fool`?

Comment: I was so blind. Yes, I had another file named `foo_idiot.sql`

If you'd be so kind as to make than an answer, I will accept it. @techraf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Command-line completion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) in most *nix shells "tries" to provide a unique string fitting current command/argument when user presses <kbd>tab</kbd>.

In case of ambiguity, shell provides longest unique string and waits for user input to resolve ambiguity.

In your case it is likely that you have a directory with a name starting with `foo` and with fourth character different from `-` (hence the longest common string is `foo`).

In case of doubt you can press <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> and by default shell will display possible choices.

In bash you can also set an option to display choices on first <kbd>tab</kbd> press by adding the following to `.bash_profile`:

```
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"
```